# Facebook subscription API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

When making a POST to subscribe to Facebook, Facebook issues a GET with the callback URL with the following query parameter:

- hub.mode
- hub.challenge
- hub.verify_token

Once we verify the mode and the token and return the `hub.challenge` does Facebook respond with a status message? It is not clear in the docs...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct it is not clear in the documentation.  What happens on your end when you subscribe?  If you get something viable, then click the Report Documentation Bug at the bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ and log the issue.